# $stateProvider does not redirect. ngRoute was working fine. But had to switch to angular-ui-router for multiple and nested views loading

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router

Developing a POC for an application.

Technologies being used : `ASP.Net MVC4` and `AngularJs`.

Initialy while getting started i was using `ngRoute` and `$routeProvider`. The links used to redirect to the server to the required controller action and pages used to load in the div marked with `ng-view` directive. But my requirement was to laod multiple and nested views. So, had to switch to `$stateProvider` which supports such requirements.

Now i am facing the issue of the links not getting redirected. The "Project" link redirects but the "Opportunity" does not. My requirement is to load a view inside the first div and then one more view into AddOpportunityContainer

Following below is the code which i had written. Can anyone help me what wrong i have been doing. Had already spent quite an amount of tme on it.

Referred Libraries:
`angular.js` and `angular-ui-router.js`

The Code:

```
var GuidanceApp = angular.module('GuidanceApp', ['ui.router']);

var configFunction = function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('Projects', {
            url: '/Projects',
            templateUrl: 'Projects/Index'
        })
        .state('Opportunity', {
            url: '/Opportunity',
            templateUrl: '/Opportunity/Index',
            views:{
                "AddOportunityContainer": {
                    templateUrl: '/Opportunity/Create'
                }
            }
        });


}
configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider'];
GuidanceApp.config(configFunction);
```

Following is the HTML of home page. And as you can see, the last div is marked with `ui-view` now instead of `ng-view` as in case of `ngRoute` and `$routeProvider`

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/#/Projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/Opportunity">Opportunity</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/Adjustments">Adjustments</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/Summary">Summary</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Different partial view to be loaded on click of Opportunity link.

```
<h2>Opportunity-Index</h2>

<div ui-view="AddOportunityContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I found the issue. It was a lame mistake. Forgot to register configFunction with GuidanceApp.config(). Missed this line - GuidanceApp.config(configFunction);

Comment: Have edited the question. The first link works. Which is a simple one to get one view. The Second link does not, in which i am trying to load nested views

Answer (score 1):

Your link for anchor element should be corrected as below without leading '/':

```
<li><a href="#/Projects">Projects</a></li>
```

Comment: I found the issue. It was a lame mistake. Forgot to register configFunction with GuidanceApp.config(). Missed this line - GuidanceApp.config(configFunction);